# Take out Quantity from Id with higher Dispatch quantity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am new over here and i am come up with scenario that i have to take out quantity from those where there is dispatch. For example i have table below

```
ID  SKU   QtyRec  QTYDisp
1   001A   50      0
2   001A   50      10
3   001A   50      20
4   001A   50      0
```

I have take out 40 Quantity. It should first pick from id 3 then id 2 then from 1 or 4. Because Dispatch Quantity is greater in 3 then in 2. But in my current scenario it is picking 40 from id 1.

```
DECLARE @Data table (Id int identity(1,1)
, SKU varchar(10)
, QtyRec INT
,QtyDis INT
)
DECLARE @Qty int = 20

INSERT @Data VALUES
('001A', 50 ,0),
('001A', 50,10 ),
('001A', 50 ,20),
('001A', 50,0)


;WITH sumqty AS 
(
    SELECT *, SUM(QtyRec) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Id) AS TotalQty FROM @Data
)
,takeqty AS (
SELECT *, 
CASE 
    WHEN @Qty >= TotalQty THEN QtyRec 
    ELSE @Qty - ISNULL(LAG(TotalQty) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Id), 0)
END AS TakeQty
FROM sumqty
)
SELECT * FROM takeqty WHERE TakeQty > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should order by `QtyDis DESC` and not by `Id ASC`:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
    (
      Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      SKU VARCHAR(10) ,
      QtyRec INT ,
      QtyDis INT
    )
DECLARE @Qty INT = 70

INSERT  @Data
VALUES  ( '001A', 50, 0 ),
        ( '001A', 50, 10 ),
        ( '001A', 50, 20 ),
        ( '001A', 50, 0 );
WITH    sumqty
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        SUM(QtyRec - QtyDis) OVER ( PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY QtyDis DESC, Id ) AS TotalQty
               FROM     @Data
             ),
        takeqty
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        CASE WHEN @Qty > TotalQty THEN TotalQty
                             ELSE @Qty
                                  - ISNULL(LAG(TotalQty) OVER ( PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY QtyDis DESC, Id ),
                                           0)
                        END AS TakeQty
               FROM     sumqty
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    takeqty
    WHERE   TakeQty > 0
```

Output:

```
Id  SKU     QtyRec  QtyDis  TotalQty    TakeQty
3   001A    50      20      30          30
2   001A    50      10      70          40
```

Comment: it is taking 50 from id 3 where as it should take 30 from id 3  because remaining quantity after subtracting QtyRec and QtyDis is 30.